# How to use onActivityResult in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, onactivityresult

I want to use *onActivityResult* in RecyclerView.Adapter. But I don't understand how this release in my situation. I have a dynamic RecyclerView.Adapter

**RecyclerView.Adapter:**

```
public class SettingsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<SettingsTypeModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;
    int total_types;


    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutIncome;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutCosts;
    EditText editIncome;
    EditText editCosts;

    public MoneyTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textInputLayoutIncome = (TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutIncome);
        editIncome = (EditText) textInputLayoutIncome.findViewById(R.id.editIncome);

        textInputLayoutCosts = (TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCosts);
        editCosts = (EditText) textInputLayoutCosts.findViewById(R.id.editCosts);
        }
    }
    public static class SendToMailTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Switch switchSendMailReport;

        public SendToMailTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            switchSendMailReport = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchSendMailReport);
        }
    }

    public static class SendToDriveTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Switch switchDriveReport;

        public SendToDriveTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            switchDriveReport = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchDriveReport);
        }
    }

    public SettingsRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<SettingsTypeModel> data, Context context) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;
        total_types = dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_MAIL:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_send_to_mail, parent, false);
                return new SendToMailTypeViewHolder(view);
            case SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_DRIVE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_send_to_drive, parent, false);
                return new SendToDriveTypeViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (dataSet.get(position).type) {
            case 4:
                return SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_MAIL;
            case 5:
                return SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_DRIVE;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        SettingsTypeModel object = dataSet.get(listPosition);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.type) {
                case SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_MAIL:

                    ((SendToMailTypeViewHolder) holder).switchSendMailReport.setChecked(false);
                    ((SendToMailTypeViewHolder) holder).switchSendMailReport.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {

                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //       switchSendMailReport.setChecked(getSwitchSendReportMail());

                    break;

                case SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_DRIVE:

                    ((SendToDriveTypeViewHolder) holder).switchDriveReport.setChecked(false);
                    ((SendToDriveTypeViewHolder) holder).switchDriveReport.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                ((SendToDriveTypeViewHolder) holder).switchDriveReport.setChecked(false);

                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataSet.size();
        }
     }
```

**Activity:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings);

        ArrayList<SettingsTypeModel> list= new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SettingsTypeModel(SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_MAIL));
        list.add(new SettingsTypeModel(SettingsTypeModel.TYPE_SEND_TO_DRIVE));

        SettingsRecyclerAdapter adapter = new SettingsRecyclerAdapter(list,this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerVieww);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setClickable(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

After clicking to *switchSendMailReport* or switchDriveReport I need to call a function *onActivityResult*.

How to use *onActivityResult* in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an `interface` in your `SettingsRecyclerAdapter` :

```
  public interface OnAdapterResult {
            public void onAdapterResult(boolean isChecked);
        }
```

and Attach the interface in it's constructor :

```
 public SettingsRecyclerAdapter (Context context){
            mContext = context;
            // .. Attach the interface
            try{
                onAdapterResult = (OnAdapterResult) context;
            }catch(ClassCastException ex){

                Log.e("MyAdapter","error"+ ex,);
            }
        }
```

then init your interface method :

```
((SendToMailTypeViewHolder) holder).switchSendMailReport.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                         boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                            onAdapterResult.onAdapterResult(isChecked); \\ here
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

then `implements` Your `SettingsActivity` from `adepter.OnAdapterResult` `interface` :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements adepter.OnAdapterResult {
.
.
.


    @Override
        public void onAdapterResult(boolean isChecked) {
            // 
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I understand you. Your answer is work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use activity's onActivityResult() inside your adapter class.
but you can create your own same method in the adapter class

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        // do you stuff
     }
```

Now from activity when you get call back in onActivityResult()
call your adapter method

```
if(adapter !=null){
   adapter.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
}
```